# How to delete one specific key value pair in dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

This is my  dict:

```
{'posid': 1, 'dollarwert': 1.1825674631151857}
{'posid': 2, 'dollarwert': 1.1831745916128784}
{'posid': 3, 'dollarwert': 1.1900826486130591}
{'posid': 4, 'dollarwert': 1.1895868303883927}
{'posid': 5, 'dollarwert': 1.1946998116397385}
{'posid': 6, 'dollarwert': 1.198615109611155}
```

and i want to delete e.g. posid 4 and the dollarwert

so my result should look like this:

```
{'posid': 1, 'dollarwert': 1.1825674631151857}
{'posid': 2, 'dollarwert': 1.1831745916128784}
{'posid': 3, 'dollarwert': 1.1900826486130591}
{'posid': 5, 'dollarwert': 1.1946998116397385}
{'posid': 6, 'dollarwert': 1.198615109611155}
```

what is the cleanest Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Those dictionaries are independent of each other, so I suppose they are elements of a list ?
In that case you could develop a function that allows you to delete the list element ( a whole dictionary ) based on the value of the "posid" key.

```
DICT=[{'posid': 1, 'dollarwert': 1.1825674631151857},
{'posid': 2, 'dollarwert': 1.1831745916128784},
{'posid': 3, 'dollarwert': 1.1900826486130591},
{'posid': 4, 'dollarwert': 1.1895868303883927},
{'posid': 5, 'dollarwert': 1.1946998116397385},
{'posid': 6, 'dollarwert': 1.198615109611155}]

def remove_dict(n):
    ind=None
    for i,d in enumerate(DICT):
        if d["posid"]==n:
            ind=i
            break
    
    if ind:
        DICT.pop(ind)
      
remove_dict(4)
print (DICT)
```

Keep in mind that the function works only if the function is in the same environment as your "DICT" list. Otherwise you will be forced to exploit the filtering method within the function somewhere else, for example with a class.